# RangeError: length > kMaxLength when starting meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm getting the following error when I start my meteor server:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           

buffer.js:194
      this.parent = new SlowBuffer(this.length);
                    ^
RangeError: length > kMaxLength
  at new Buffer (buffer.js:194:21)
  at fs.js:226:16
  at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file over 1.7 Gb in your `private` or `public` folder will cause this error. Create a new folder with a dot infront of it. Meteor will ignore that folder on startup

For example: `.data` and put all your big files in it.

> When I put a file that is over 1.7gb into public, it seems that meteor
>   tries to read the file into memory and crashes.

[Reference](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1129)